# Rendering smooth ground

Tags: terrain, normals

I'm attempting to render terrain made out of a triangle mesh. The problem is that whenever I have a northwest -> southeast ramp in the terrain, I get this diamond pattern:

[image]

The issue is that at the top and bottom of the ramp, the terrain is more flat than at the middle, so if the ramp is aligned with the triangles, each triangle will have two light vertices (at the top and bottom), and one dark vertex (at the middle).

How can I fix this effect? Subdividing the mesh helps, but doesn't fix it completely.

Vertex shader:

```
uniform mat4 projection;
attribute vec3 position;
attribute vec3 normal;
attribute vec4 color;

varying vec3 f_position;
varying vec3 f_normal;
varying vec4 f_color;

void main(void) {
    gl_Position = projection * position;
    f_color = color;
    f_normal = normal;
    f_position = position;
}
```

Fragment shader:

```
varying vec3 f_position;
varying vec3 f_normal;
varying vec4 f_color;

uniform vec3 light_position;

void main(void) {
    float light = 0.5 + 0.5 * abs(dot(normalize(f_normal), normalize(light_position - f_position)));
    gl_FragColor = vec4(light, light, light, 1) * f_color;
}
```

Comment: Do per Fragment and not per Vertex lighting

Comment: show your shaders

Comment: Welcome to a StackExchange site! If you've managed to solve the issue by yourself, the way to go is to post an answer and mark it as accepted, this way, the future users that encounter an issue similar to yours will get a clue on what to do. If you do not want to post an answer, then either delete it yourself, or leave it be.